# java.nio.file Files.createDirectory on windows remote mount share

Tags: java, java.nio.file

I seem to not be able to let java create directories on Windows mount shares (like \myshare\directory\subdir).

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.logging.*;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        Path target = Paths.get("\\\\DISK\\Remote\\DirectoPO");
        try
        {
            Files.createDirectory(target);
        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

I always get a

```
SEVERE: null
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: \\DISK\Remote\DirectoPO
```

However I can access the share without any problem (I'm Administrator on my machine and Administrators can create directories on this mount share).
Any help?

Comment: Hey @dendini Did you solve it, I have a similar problem